# Is a "listen again" service available for Beats 1?

Tags: apple-music, itunes-radio

As a *non*-subscriber to Apple Music, I *can* listen live to Beats 1 but sadly the show I want to listen to (Zane Lowe) is on at times I am never free (5pm/am)

I understand you can see a playlist of past shows but am unclear if even paying subscribers can listen to previous shows on-demand... something which has become pretty standard in the UK through services such as iPlayer.

Is there a free/paid way to listen to Beats 1 radio shows on demand and if so, what are the details?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as an Apple Music subscriber, I can verify that paid Apple Music subscribers may go back and listen to replays of most Beats 1 shows on-demand. I personally use this feature to catch up on Zane Lowe all the time. It will allow you to go back and listen to shows up to a couple months old. For example, right now I could go back and listen to many shows from December 2015, but not any earlier.

This is part of the regular Apple Music service, so it also gives you access to on-demand tracks from (much of) iTunes, iTunes Radio, and For You.

$5 per month - student

$10 per month - individual

$15 per month - family

[image: Featured Shows to Replay]
[image: Zane Lowe]
[image: Zane Lowe Replays]